# XML Schema for same element name with different attributes and elements

Tags: xslt, xsd

I'm trying to make an XML Schema - for what's in my opinion a difficult structure. Let's say I have these XML members within a'members'-tag.

```
<member name="any_name" tab="any_tab" class="any_class">
    <summary>Summary</summary>
</member>
```

and

```
<member name="any_name" tab="any_tab">
    <type class="class_name">
        <member name="Name">
            <summary>Summary</summary>
        </member>
    </type>
</member>
```

Only the name-attribute of a member is required in this context.

I want to be able to validate both of these structures. To do so, I tried to define two complexType's:

```
<xs:complexType name="normalmember">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="summary" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="tab" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="class" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

and

```
<xs:complexType name="typemember">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="typememberinfo" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="class" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

My problem is that I can't define two 'member' elements with different types in the same scope:

```
    <xs:element name="members">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="member" type="normalmember"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="member" type="typemember"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

How can I make an XML-Schema which is able to validate both structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible this rule is called "Element Declarations Consistent".

> The Element Declarations Consistent rule for model groups
>   (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-element-consistent) rules out
>   inconsistent element declarations like the following two conflicting
>   definitions of element , i.e.,  cannot be both an "int" and a
>   "string" in the same group:
>
> ```
>     (example-1)
> <xs:complexType name="example-1">   
>      <xs:sequence>
>          <xs:element name="a" type="xs:int"/>
>          <xs:element name="whatever"/>
>          <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>   
>      </xs:sequence> 
> </xs:complexType>
> ```